# Data structures questions

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

1. Can we sort 7 numbers in 10 comparisons?
2. Depth of a binary tree with n node is? log(n)+1 or something else
3. If every node in a binary tree has either 0 or 2 children then the height of the tree is log(n): is it true or false?
4. Inserting an element into a binary search tree of size n takes time proportional to ------?

Comment: Please have a look for http://cs.stackexchange.com/. This might be the right forum for your questions.

Answer (score 0):

2. A binary tree not balanced can have all children at the right (for example), so the maximum height of a tree with n nodes is n
3. Same as 2.
4. If the tree is not balanced the insertion is proportional to the number of nodes that you need to traverse to find the correct position. Potentially n nodes.